# How can angular velocity ever be variable when linear velocity remains constant in magnitude under uniform circular motion?

Tags: rotational-kinematics

So, the magnitude of the linear or tangential velocity of an object is equal to the product of angular velocity and radius of the circle. So, under uniform circular motion, the linear velocity remains the same in magnitude, and from the relation stated above, angular velocity should also remain constant and that implies angular acceleration of the object will be 0. But this contradicts the equality,  magnitude of centripetal acceleration=radius×angular acceleration, as centripetal  acceleration will be a non-zero value but we will get 0 on RHS due to angular acceleration being 0. So, what am I getting wrong here ?

Comment: Angular acceleration and centripetal acceleration are orthogonal vectors

Comment: Your statement " magnitude of centripetal acceleration =radius×angular acceleration" is wrong.

Comment: Check out chapter 1 Kleppner and Kolenkow

Comment: @trula , centripetal acceleration(a)=dv/dt=d(radius.angular displacement)/dt=radius.d(angular displacement)/dt=radius. angular velocity.

Comment: You mix vectors v  and there absolute values $|v|=\omega*|r|$ so your equation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In *uniform circular motion*, the linear velocity is *not* constant: Its magnitude is, but its *direction* is continuously changing. That change requires the application of a force, which produces an acceleration. The direction of that force necessary to achieve uniform circular motion is at right angles to the instantaneous velocity, pointing towards the rotation center, and that is the direction of the perceived acceleration. Since the force does not point in the direction of motion, it performs no work on the system.